# AWS Cloudwatch custom math metric to read on SQS metrics for an ASG dynamic scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a custom metric that pretty much reads `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` of over 25 SQS queues, I will use this metric in order to spin up instances based off some math.

I would like to use this for a dynamic scaling and I've been following the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-target-tracking-metric-math.html).

This bellow code is what I send as the target tracking configuration (`aws autoscaling put-scaling-policy --target-tracking-configuration`) and this works fine as long as I don't have more than 10 queue Metrics.

```json
{
    "CustomizedMetricSpecification": {
        "Metrics": [
            {
                "Label": "Get the queue size (the number of messages waiting to be processed)",
                "Id": "m1",
                "MetricStat": {
                    "Metric": {
                        "MetricName": "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible",
                        "Namespace": "AWS/SQS",
                        "Dimensions": [
                            {
                                "Name": "QueueName",
                                "Value": "my-queue"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Stat": "Sum"
                },
                "ReturnData": false
            },

            ... many more up to 25

            {
                "Label": "Get the group size (the number of InService instances)",
                "Id": "mx",
                "MetricStat": {
                    "Metric": {
                        "MetricName": "GroupInServiceInstances",
                        "Namespace": "AWS/AutoScaling",
                        "Dimensions": [
                            {
                                "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                                "Value": "my-asg"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Stat": "Average"
                },
                "ReturnData": false
            },
            {
                "Label": "Calculate the backlog per instance",
                "Id": "e1",
                "Expression": "m1 +m2 +m3 .../ mx",
                "ReturnData": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "TargetValue": 100
}
```

So far I can't add more than 10 Metric stats on my scaling policy without getting an error: `A customized metric specification can’t have more than 10 MetricStat objects`

Is there a way to do it?
Can I create a custom Metric directly into cloudwatch reading those SQS metrics then call it from within my scaling policy?

Cheers